# Is there a best-pratice for adapting the interfaces of STL containers?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, adapter

Inheriting from STL containers can lead to undefined behavior and should mostly be avoided. Is there a best practice for adapting the interface of STL containers? Typing all the functions again and again for different containers makes no sense, so I am interested if a set of generic adapters can do the job, and what would they look like.

For example, a part of the interface is common to all containers:

```
template
<
    typename Type,    
    template<typename, typename> class Sequence,
    template <typename T> class Allocator = std::allocator
>
class CommonInterface
{
    public: 

        using container_type = Sequence<Type, Allocator<Type>>; 

        using value_type             = typename container_type::value_type;     
        using allocator_type         = typename container_type::allocator_type; 
        using size_type              = typename container_type::size_type; 
        using difference_type        = typename container_type::difference_type; 
        ...

        decltype(auto) begin()
        {
            return data_.begin(); 
        }

        decltype(auto) cbegin() const 
        {
            return data_.cbegin(); 
        }

        ...      

    protected: 
        container_type data_; 
};
```

but this doesn't work for `std::array`. Also there are containers which support O(1) direct access, and those that don't, so I can extract pieces of the interface into generic adapters (for everything apart `array`) and use inheritance to open the interface I guess.

This smells to me, and the amount of typing is annoying.

Unfortunately, it seems I will need something like this, because I need to introduce a lot of **different types** in my library, that are essentially **STL containers.** I'm using tags and SFINAE to distinguish between the (geometrical) types when choosing algorithms.

**Edit**: What would you do to model a polygon (a *closed chain* of points) and a polyline (an *open* chain of points, same storage) using **any** (**possibly same**) STL container?

Comment: `Inheriting from STL containers can lead to undefined behavior` - not really. Inheriting from STL container is well-defined. It is still unclear what your end goal is. Why do you need an adapter in the first place?

Comment: The approach taken by the standard is to provide free-standing functions like [`std::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin). They work with containers, `std::array`, plain C arrays.

Comment: @SergeyA: now I am completely lost. I have people telling me that STL containers don't have virtual destructors, I have deleted the new operator because of this in the past (see my previous questions), others telling me it's OK...

Comment: A class `D` inheriting from standard containers -- or, in fact, any class `P` with a non-virtual destructor -- *could* lead to UB if you were to allocate one dynamically and delete it through a pointer to `P`. However that's a pretty specific scenario which I don't think qualifies as a general rule. Even moreso for standard containers -- I have never encountered something like `void f(std::unique_ptr<std::vector<Bla>>)` that's the intersection of ownership transfer, polymorphism and dynamically-allocated containers.

Comment: That is why you do not publicly inherit from them.  private inheritance is OK.

Comment: @NathanOliver: don't I have to re-open the interface if I have privately inherited? In essence, it's like composition, if I remember the GoF book, composition should be preferred to private inheritance?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: to me, the effect of providing free-standing functions is the same, compared to public member function of an adapter: I have to type my fingers off. That is the core of my question. :) What do you guys do in this case?

Comment: @tmaric Yes, you would have to use a lot of using statements to rebuild the public interface but at least you don't have to worry about someone passing your type to a function that take reference to the parent class.

Comment: Not having a virtual destructor would lead to UB only if the object is deleted through dynamic type which is different from it's static type. When this is not the case, UB doesn't happen. And yes, STL containers are not polymorphic, but inheritance is not equal with polymorphism.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Just to make sure I understand, you propose to compose an STL container and then provide free-standing functions like `std::begin`?

Comment: I don't propose anything in particular as I don't really understand your problem. But looking at your `CommonInterface` example - the standard achieves the same goal by providing free functions *instead of* composing, not in addition to. Why again do you feel the need to compose, or inherit, in the first place?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: imagine you have 3 points on a plane (a, b and c). They can build a triangle (a closed chain a-b, b-c, c-a). They can also be an open chain of line segments (a-b, b-c). The 3 points are stored in a same STL container.  Now you want to compute the area of the triangle and the point-chain. You can tag the triangle type (if it were a separate type) with `triangle_tag` and the point-chain with the`point_chain_tag` and use tags and dispatch, or SFINAE to make sure that `area(PointChain&& p)` is always 0. However, if you just plug points into same STL containers, the types are same.

Comment: Well, an `int` means different things in different places, but one doesn't commonly write wrappers around `int` for each possible use.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: In this case, there is no way around it, as algorithms should recognize which type is being used. Is an `stl::vector<point>` a triangle, or a chain of points.

Comment: Doesn't the caller know what a given `stl::vector<point>` instance represent? Why would it call `area` on a chain of points?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ok forget the area then, and use an intersection with a halfspace. In this case, an open chain has a missing edge. Same algorithm, same storage, different types, different result. And thanks for taking the time for this! :)

Comment: Pass in a flag or something to indicate how to interpret the vector. If you insist, have two different structs with the vector as a public member; the structs would serve essentially as a type tag.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Thanks for the tip, I tried passing a flag (and using value-based tag disptach). It becomes a problem to handle, already if the function template has 3 arguments, then usually dispatch function is used, etc (see boost::geometry). Basically, I found a really neat solution to this, it's called "overloading functions based on arbitrary properties of types" and it uses SFINAE to check which types are to be used. The only issue I have left is wrapping STL containers quickly into my new models, in terms of typing up a ton of forwarding functions (member or free).

Comment: I was suggesting something like `struct Polygon { std::vector<point> points; };` and `struct Polyline { std::vector<point> points; };`. This way you have distinct types to hang overload resolution off of, and also direct access to the list of points, so you don't need to forward methods or anything.